# How to use cache in Rails for other formats than xml (like csv)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a rails controller which must return a .csv file and I'd like this page to use cache.
The cache works fine when I use a .xml format (it returns 304 http status), but when the format is csv, it always returns 200 http status.

here is my controller code:

```
  def index
    @machines = Machine.all
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.xml { render :xml => @machines.to_xml }
      wants.csv
    end
  end
```

I've tried to put

```
  caches_page :index
```

but it doesn't work.